# Log all HashMap keys and values using slf4j Logger

Tags: java, logging, slf4j

How can I log HashMap keys and values using slf4j logger. I've trying this a couple of times but still figured out.

The following code just only logs the "test values" string without the values of maps arguments.

```
  public void test(HashMap maps) {
      logger.info("test values", maps);
  }
```

Answer (score 15):

Your code is using this overload (see [javadoc](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/Logger.html#info-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-))

> `void info(String message, Object p0)`
>
> Logs a message with parameters at info level.

That overload will *substitute* the string representation of `p0` into the `message` template string, replacing the first substitution marker with the representation.  But you don't have any substitution markers in your message!

Here is a quick fix:

```
  public void test(HashMap maps) {
      logger.info("test values {}", maps);
  }
```

Related Question:

- [How to log the second argument in log4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755046/how-to-log-the-second-argument-in-log4j)

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you try like this to iterate in the HashMap.

```
public void printMap(Map mp) {
    Iterator it = mp.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        logger.info(pair.getKey() + " = " + pair.getValue());
    }
}
```

There are more examples and approaches in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898/how-to-efficiently-iterate-over-each-entry-in-a-map).

Comment: I only want to log all the keys and values once not one log per key and value pair.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to print maps in logging. Sharing some ways below -

1. Use the logger to print maps in your logs:

   ```
   Map<String, Object> yourMap = // Your map here

   logger.info("Printing map: " + yourMap.toString());
   ```

   This code will print the map in your log output as a string. You can use the toString() method of the map to convert it into a string representation. Note that this method might not be the most readable or useful if you have complex maps.
2. Iterate over the map and log its key-value pairs individually

   ```
   Map<String, Object> yourMap = // Your map here

   for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : yourMap.entrySet()) {
       logger.info("Key: " + entry.getKey() + ", Value: " + entry.getValue());
   }
   ```

   This will log each key-value pair in a separate log entry.
3. Use libraries like Apache Commons Lang or third-party JSON libraries for a more structured and readable output. Here's an example using Apache Commons Lang.

   ```
   Map<String, Object> yourMap = // Your map here

   // Using Apache Commons Lang to print the map in a more readable format

   String mapString = ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(yourMap, ToStringStyle.JSON_STYLE);

   logger.info("Map: " + mapString);
   ```
4. List item Another example with  JSON serialization with Jackson

   ```
   // Using Jackson to print the map as JSON
   try {
       ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
       String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(yourMap);
       logger.info("JSON Map: " + json);
   } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to log each key-value pair on a separate line or with more custom formatting, you would iterate over the map entries:

```
public void test(HashMap<?, ?> maps) {
    for (Map.Entry<?, ?> entry : maps.entrySet()) {
        logger.info("Key: {}, Value: {}", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
}
```